# ClickOnce Application Files dialog filename problem

Tags: deployment, file, clickonce, visual-studio-2008-sp1

In the ClickOnce "Application Files" files dialog, most of the entries for files are listed with the name "C".  I have seen this on a colleague's machine for a different project as well.  Has anyone else seen this and is there a way to get the correct filename inserted?  We are both using VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this happening. Do you mean the filename is just displayed as C, with nothing else after it? What happens if you click the ResetAll button in the bottom right corner of the Application Files dialog?

What's actually in the \bin\Debug or \bin\Release folder after you build?

Comment: Yes, there about about 15 assemblyies with the filenames listed as "C".  The files themselves are all in the bin directory.  Doing a ResetAll makes no difference.  I don't see an easy way to upload an image or I would show the dialog.

Comment: I'm going to ask the ClickOnce Product Team if they've ever heard of this happening. I'll report back.

Comment: Is it the main project's assemblies, the other project's assemblies, 3rd party assemblies that are added to the project? Is there a pattern at all to which ones are messed up?

Comment: When you publish, do the assemblies end up in the app manifest with the right file names? Or do they all say C? The ClickOnce team asks if you can create a sample project that has the problem and create a bug in connect.microsoft.com and upload the project? If you can do that, can you post the link here, and I'll pass it along. The bug should go under Visual Studio. Thanks.